# Why is the prayer for dreams repeated in Birchas Kohanim?

Tags: tefilla, yom-tov, chutz-laaretz, birchas-kohanim, dream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who says the Ribbono shel Olam's in Birkas Kohanim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5514/who-says-the-ribbono-shel-olams-in-birkas-kohanim)

At [Birchas Kohanim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priestly_Blessing) outside Israel, where it is only said on Yom Tov (Ashkenazim), we say twice a prayer for bad dreams. Why do we say the same prayer twice? Why is it not enough to say it once?

Comment: People have a lot of dreams between yamim tovim!

Comment: In between the minute it takes to say the few words?

Comment: @GershonGold overnight

Comment: @GershonGold No. people have many bad dreams in between goes so they need to say the prayer a bunch of times. (I'm half joking about this in the sense that I don't buy it but I bet someone says it.)