# Bad dream about others

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, dream, friendship

Someone had a dream that some very bad things happened to his friend/relative/other. What should someone do after having such a dream? Is this is a sign of something? Perhaps one should do Teshuva? Maybe the friend/relative/other should do Teshuva? What can be said about having "bad dreams" about other people?

Comment: Slightly related: [Here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5514/) and [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10502/). [This page](http://ohr.edu/ask/ask134.htm) is also somewhat relevant, and mentions the concepts of *hatavas chalom* and *ta'anis chalom*.

Comment: We do say in birkas kohanim בין שחלמו אחרים עלי

Comment: also [relevant](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10504/702)

Comment: "All dreams follow their interpretations" - Berachos 56a. Find a good interpretation!

Answer (score 6):

The person who had the dream should do a *hatavat chalom* with three good friends. It's found in some siddurim (I believe the Artscroll interlinear has it)

It should be pointed out, though, that the interpretation of dreams can be very counterintuitive and is in fact usually the opposite of what you would expect. See [Shulchan Aruch O.C. 288](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.288.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), where a dream of someone dying is a good dream, seeing yourself getting married is a bad dream, and so on - so be aware that this may not be a bad dream at all according to the Jewish interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

I was once told to instruct the individual who resembled a character in a dream to do Teshuvah, and to never say a dream was "bad", but rather say it was "a dream that disturbed me". I was also told to do a Hatavath Halom.