# Why don't the kohanim chant in Israel?

Tags: minhag, eretz-yisrael, music, birchas-kohanim

One of the things i happen to miss from chag in America is the chanting during Bircat Kohanim. Before the last word of each pasuk, they chant for a while. ([Some people](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5514/5151) use this time to say a prayer against bad dreams.)

It seems to me that people living in Israel also deserve this chance. If every day is too often, why not just on chagim?

I don't recall hearing this done at all in Israel, even on chagim. Anyone know why not?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20392/759

Comment: The same reason that a weekday Shacharis rushes through, but a yom kippur shacharis goes on and on ... The rarity of the event.

Comment: Probably because people are running to work, so they don't have time to sing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach (עלהו לא יבול p96) maintains that the Israeli custom is not to say this prayer at all.

Nonetheless, one who has had a bad dream and wishes to say the תפילה, can do so during שים שלום.

Source: [שיח תפילה](http://olamot.net/sites/default/files/pdfimages/9_49.png)

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14801